# Eclipse Kepler: Installing Plugins for Juno

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, backwards-compatibility

I just downloaded Eclipse Kepler (version 4.3), and the first thing I did was install my Google Plugin for Eclipse (Android, GWT, etc.). Since there currently isn't a version of the plugin for Kepler, how reliable would it be to install and use the plugin version designed for Juno (4.2)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it will work perfectly fine, there is no major differences, normally supported versions are preferred but eclipse is backward compatible and I don't see an issue there.